# How to add the relevant caption to a random image in a different div?

Tags: jquery

I don't know quite where to start with this idea. I'm using the jQuery below to show a random image with each page load. I'd like to extend it to show a specific caption with each image that is displayed in a different div.

The function below outputs a random image.jpg in the format image1.jpg, image2.jpg, etc. I'm thinking I need an array of the captions for each image, but how can I reference the array and output the caption by the image name in the function?

```
<script>
(function($){

    $.randomImage = {
        defaults: {

            path: 'headerimages/',

            myImages: ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg','image3.jpg','image4.jpg','image5.jpg','image6.jpg' ]         
        }           
    }

    $.fn.extend({
            randomImage:function(config) {

                var config = $.extend({}, $.randomImage.defaults, config); 

                 return this.each(function() {

                        var imageNames = config.myImages;

                        var imageNamesSize = imageNames.length;

                        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*imageNamesSize);

                        var displayImage = imageNames[randomNumber];

                        var fullPath = config.path + displayImage;

                        $(this).attr( { src: fullPath, alt: displayImage });
                }); 
            }
    });

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

The image from the function above is displayed by the html `<img class="randomheader" src="" alt="image">`

The caption will be in a different div, i.e. `<div class="caption"></div>`
The CSS for `#caption` would probably be `display:none` until the jQuery loads.

This is the doc ready function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.randomheader').randomImage();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use colon : seperated caption and image name e.g [ 'your caption 1:image1.jpg', 'your caption 2:image2.jpg' ]. then use javascript split to separate caption and image.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<script>
(function($){

$.randomImage = {
    defaults: {

        path: 'headerimages/',

        myImages: ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg','image3.jpg','image4.jpg','image5.jpg','image6.jpg' ],
        myCaptions: ['caption1', 'caption2','caption3','caption4','caption5','caption6' ]          
    }           
}

$.fn.extend({
        randomImage:function(config) {

            var config = $.extend({}, $.randomImage.defaults, config); 

             return this.each(function() {

                    var imageNames = config.myImages;

                    var imageCaptions = config.myCaptions;

                    var imageNamesSize = imageNames.length;

                    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*imageNamesSize);

                    var displayImage = imageNames[randomNumber];

                    var displayCaption = imageCaptions[randomNumber];

                    var fullPath = config.path + displayImage;

                    $(this).attr( { src: fullPath, alt: displayImage });
                    $("#caption").html(displayCaption);
            }); 
        }
});

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. One additional idea: do you know how I can get the caption to fadeIn? I tried $("#caption").html(displayCaption).fadeIn('slow'); with no luck.

Comment: fadeIn won't work because #caption is visible. Try $('#caption').hide().html(displayCaption).fadeIn('slow');

Answer (score 0):

add an array of captions to the $.randomImage.defaults & config objects.
Then retrieve using `var caption = config.captions[randomNumber];`

or

change `myImages: ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg','image3.jpg'`...
to `myImages: [{image: 'image1.jpg', caption: 'My Caption},`...